# FULL OUTER JOIN cannot be used without a condition that is an equality of fields from both sides of the join

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have 3 tables like

table_4

- name
- phone
- email
- additionalColumns4

table_5

- phone
- additionalColumns5

table_6

- phone
- email
- additionalColumns6

Each table have different pieces of data.

I want to create one big table, with all possible data connected(one person is in 1 and 3 table , second just in 2 table etc) –  and want to merge it in one big table like .

- table4.name
- table4.phone
- table4.email
- table4.additionalColumns4
- table5.phone
- table5.additionalColumns5
- table6.phone
- table6.email
- table6.additionalColumns6

  SELECT
  *
  FROM
      table_4
  FULL JOIN
      table_5
          ON
              table_5_field_s_mail_dmp_id =table_4_field_email_dmp_id
  FULL JOIN
      table_6
            ON
                 table_6_field_phone2_dmp_id     =table_4_field_phone_dmp_id

works excellent,but

```
  SELECT
    *
  FROM
    table_4 
  FULL JOIN
    table_5
  ON
    table_5_field_s_mail_dmp_id =table_4_field_email_dmp_id
  FULL JOIN
    table_6
  ON
       table_6_field_phone2_dmp_id     =table_4_field_phone_dmp_id
    OR table_6_field_phone1_dmp_id     =table_4_field_phone_dmp_id
    OR table_6_field_workphone_dmp_id  =table_4_field_phone_dmp_id
    OR table_6_field_addphone_dmp_id   =table_4_field_phone_dmp_id
    OR table_6_field_email_dmp_id      =table_5_field_s_mail_dmp_id
    OR table_6_field_email_dmp_id      =table_4_field_email_dmp_id
```

returns

**Error: FULL OUTER JOIN cannot be used without a condition that is an equality of fields from both sides of the join.**

I can'not undestand this error and how to solve my problem

Added
I checked

```
SELECT
  *
FROM
  table_4
FULL JOIN
  table_6
ON
  (table_6_field_phone2_dmp_id =table_4_field_phone_dmp_id
  OR table_6_field_phone1_dmp_id =table_4_field_phone_dmp_id
  )
```

And it's return the same error too. Big query not likes OR in full join conditions?

Comment: before to go in more details  - can you clarify why you need FULL OUTER JOIN here? Somehow I feel those should be LEFT JOIN - but of course I can be wrong - so please clarify. I think if you can show simplified example of your rows in tables and expected output  - this can help

Comment: I have several tables like
sales1(
*name
*phone
*additionalColumns)
sales2 
(*email
*additionalColumns)
sales3
(*phone
*email
*additionalColumns
)
I want to create one big table, with all possible data connected(one person is in 1 and 3 table , second just in 2 table etc)

Comment: "all possible data connected" is too generic statement and can mean many different things thus implementations. can you be more specific and provide simplified examples of input (3 tables) and expected output(1 table)

Comment: i edited my question and adds some examples

Answer (score 3):

Write separate queries, then use `COALESCE`. (Credit goes to Ajit Deshmukh,
 who posted [a nice example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45431044/291796).)