# Negating an equality within a temporary function WHERE statement causes a join error

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

I'm trying to count distinct users that also match a condition (in this example `deleted IS NOT TRUE`). I need to group by monthly cohorts with users who were active within the target month and users who were active in previous months.

To retrieve previous months I'm using a negated equality (`FORMAT_DATE('%Y%m', DATE(timestamp)) != CONCAT(year, month)`) but when I do I'm receiving "Error: LEFT OUTER JOIN cannot be used without a condition that is an equality of fields from both sides of the join". Using the equality without the negation runs successfully.

I've looked at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49073352/full-outer-join-cannot-be-used-without-a-condition-that-is-an-equality-of-fields) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43858433/bigquery-joining-on-multiple-conditions-using-subqueries-and-or-statements) but both of these questions are in the context of using an explicit `JOIN`.

The code below replicates the issue and can be executed in the BigQuery web console.

```
CREATE TEMPORARY FUNCTION getCurrentCount(year STRING, month STRING) AS ((
  SELECT
    COUNT(DISTINCT t.by) distinct_count
  FROM 
    `bigquery-public-data.hacker_news.full` AS t
  WHERE
    FORMAT_DATE('%Y%m', DATE(timestamp)) = CONCAT(year, month) AND
    deleted IS NOT TRUE
));

CREATE TEMPORARY FUNCTION getPreviousCount(year STRING, month STRING) AS ((
  SELECT
    COUNT(DISTINCT t.by) distinct_count
  FROM 
    `bigquery-public-data.hacker_news.full` AS t
  WHERE
    FORMAT_DATE('%Y%m', DATE(timestamp)) != CONCAT(year, month) AND
    deleted IS NOT TRUE
));

WITH easy_cohorts AS (
  SELECT
    t.by author,
    FORMAT_DATE('%Y', DATE(timestamp)) year,
    FORMAT_DATE('%m', DATE(timestamp)) month
  FROM
    `bigquery-public-data.hacker_news.full` AS t
)

SELECT
  year,
  month,
  COUNT(author) total_authors,
  getCurrentCount(year, month) distinct_current_authors,
  getPreviousCount(year, month) distinct_previous_authors
FROM
  easy_cohorts
GROUP BY
  year,
  month
ORDER BY
  year,
  month
```

Why do I get this error and how could I get around it?

Comment: What if you subtract `1` from the year and then use an equality? You may need to cast between int64 and string.

Answer (score 1):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
#standardSQL
CREATE TEMPORARY FUNCTION getCurrentCount(month DATE) AS ((
  SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT t.by) distinct_count
  FROM `bigquery-public-data.hacker_news.full` AS t
  WHERE DATE_TRUNC(DATE(TIMESTAMP), MONTH) = month 
  AND deleted IS NOT TRUE
));
CREATE TEMPORARY FUNCTION getPreviousCount(month DATE) AS ((
  SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT t.by) distinct_count
  FROM `bigquery-public-data.hacker_news.full` AS t
  WHERE DATE_TRUNC(DATE(TIMESTAMP), MONTH) = DATE_SUB(month,INTERVAL 1 MONTH)
  AND deleted IS NOT TRUE
));
WITH easy_cohorts AS (
  SELECT t.by author,
    DATE_TRUNC(DATE(TIMESTAMP), MONTH) month
  FROM `bigquery-public-data.hacker_news.full` AS t
)
SELECT month, 
  COUNT(author) total_authors,
  getCurrentCount(month) distinct_current_authors,
  getPreviousCount(month) distinct_previous_authors
FROM easy_cohorts
GROUP BY month
ORDER BY month
```

Please note: I assume your cohort logic is correct and meet your requirements. So I only fixed "retrieving" current month and previous month distinct count

Comment: I may not have made it clear in my question but I want a count of the current month and then a count of all previous months to date; not just the most recent previous month. How would suggest doing that?

Comment: No, I asked how to "retrieve previous months". I can see how reading over this quickly could be confusing but I didn't ask to "retrieve the previous month", which is the basis of this answer. As such I believe my question is still valid as it stands.

Comment: I will revisit my answer when have time.